# Android SSH does nothing

Tags: android, ssh

I created an app that connects to ssh with my raspberry Pi and executes a python file. The command and the python file work like a charm when I connect from my windows pc but the app does nothing for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageInstaller;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                try {
                    executeRemoteCommand("pi", "123456", "192.168.1.6", 22);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute(1);
    }

    public static String executeRemoteCommand(String username, String password, String hostname, int port)
            throws Exception {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)
                session.openChannel("exec");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

        // Execute command
        channelssh.setCommand("cd /home/pi/Desktop | nohup python red.py");
        //System.out.print("cd /home/pi/Desktop | nohup python red.py");
        channelssh.connect();
        channelssh.disconnect();

        return baos.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the Android Studio output:

```
10/13 17:22:17: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of D:\Android\Projects\LEDControl\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.example.seth.ledcontrol
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.seth.ledcontrol/com.example.seth.ledcontrol.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 6987 on device samsung-gt_i9195-02de24f3
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.seth.ledcontrol, real application class is null.
W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
I/PersonaManager: getPersonaService() name persona_policy
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15423: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15427: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 658: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 680: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 621: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 623: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1__release_AU ()
              OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
              Build Date: 03/25/14 Tue
              Local Branch: 
              Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.32
              Local Patches: NONE
              Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 11
I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 12
```

Comment: That logcat does not appear to be filtered for your app

Comment: Don't know how to do that...

Comment: Android Studio has a drop down next to that output for the options by which to filter. Basically, what I'm trying to point out, is that there's no errors there, nor messages from your app

Comment: The filter is set to "Show only selected application" and the only error in red is this:

10-13 17:28:22.055 12222-12222/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
10-13 17:28:22.055 12222-12222/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.example.seth.ledcontrol [ userId:0 | appId:10174 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cd` cannot be piped like that

Why are you not using the full path to the program?

```
nohup python /home/pi/Desktop/red.py
```

Comment: Thx! that worked! I used the previous command cause that is how I connect from my windows pc terminal!

Comment: I don't think it should work from any connection with a pipe like that. This is the correct usage